# Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - cannot use new lifecycle for channel 'mychannel' as it does not have the required capabilities enabled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[enter image description here][1]    2021-04-08 12:46:15.810 UTC [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] setOrdererClient -> INFO 001 Retrieved channel (mychannel) orderer endpoint: orderer.example.com:7050

```
Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - cannot use new lifecycle for channel 'mychannel' as it does not have the required capabilities enabled
```

anyone has come across this problem?

configtx.yaml

Organizations:

```
# SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
# in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
- &OrdererOrg
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git de
    Name: OrdererOrg

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: OrdererMSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

- &Org1
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org1MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org1MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
          Port: 7051
```

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

```
# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
# the application side of the network
Organizations:
```

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

```
# Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
# Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
OrdererType: solo

Addresses:
    - orderer.example.com:7050

# Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
BatchTimeout: 2s

# Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
BatchSize:

    # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
    MaxMessageCount: 10

    # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch.
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

    # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
    # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

Kafka:
    # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
    # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
    Brokers:
        - 127.0.0.1:9092

# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
# the orderer side of the network
Organizations:
```

Profiles:

```
OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
OneOrgChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
```

Comment: You nee to post the configtx.yaml file you are using. It probably needs to have the proper capability enabled under the "capabilities" section.

Comment: How I enabled "capabilities" section~

Comment: post your entire configtx.yaml content and i will show you

Comment: I have updated it,  this is my entire content~  thanks~

Comment: I mean this: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml#L103-L155

Comment: this project：https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/hyperledger-fabric-based-access-control/blob/master/basic-network/configtx.yaml

Comment: I have added Capabilities, it not works

Comment: You need to enable the v20 capability in the configtx.yaml when you create the channel

Comment: I have added Capabilities, and the error is unchanged, and the docker container of order：streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=192.168.128.6:57050 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=2.2546ms

Comment: But that is not an error, it just means that the client closed the connection.

Comment: Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities 
        V2.0: true

Comment: Channel: &ChannelDefaults   
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Comment: Profiles:
    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults

Comment: I have added these, and I will show you link later ~ thanks~

Comment: Please show exactly what you're doing - are you creating a new channel? updating this current channel? etc.

Comment: I run this command:  docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" 
cli  peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg --channelID mychannel --name abacFabric -v 1 --package-id $PACKAGE_ID --sequence 1 --signature-policy "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"

Comment: Submit the chaincode definition to the specified channel

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/hyperledger-fabric-based-access-control/blob/master/startFabric.sh

Comment: In this file https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/hyperledger-fabric-based-access-control/blob/master/basic-network/configtx.yaml you need to have capabilities

Comment: I have added:  https://github.com/lihuihui423/hyperledger-fabric-based-access-control/blob/master/basic-network/configtx.yaml

Comment: please help me check the added content ~ I met the same error~thanks

Comment: maybe you also need to add them to the profiles too?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml#L304-L318

Comment: https://github.com/lihuihui423/hyperledger-fabric-based-access-control/blob/master/basic-network/configtx.yaml

Comment: I change it, is it ok?

Comment: I think so... does it work now?

Comment: not yet ~ o(╥﹏╥)o ~ why "peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg " report this error ~I am little understand

Comment: https://github.com/lihuihui423/hyperledger-fabric-based-access-control/blob/9d0400686622cc8519951ceab0db5f31f48b7081/basic-network/configtx.yaml#L49

The capability is specified with a `.` instead of an `_` which will cause problems.

Additionally, if you are not seeing problems with that capability name, it implies you are not properly regenerating your network.  Make sure everything is deleted, including any docker volumes etc. if you are using them before trying again.